# MS-Access - Merge data between two tables base on conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am using MS Access and I am trying to create a query between two tables and merge same rows base on:

`cust_id = cust_id` and
`a_date = f_date` and
`price = paid`

and have the desire output.

**My data now:**

```
tblapp
app_id  cust_id    a_date    price  a_memo
------------------------------------------
1         1       10/10/20     20   hello
2         1       11/10/20     10   bye
3         2       12/10/20     30   hi
4         2       12/10/20     30   text
5         2       12/10/20     30   lol
6         2       12/10/20     30   ciao
7         3       14/10/20     25   peace

tblfin
fin_id  cust_id    f_date     paid
----------------------------------
1         1       10/10/20     20
2         1       11/10/20     10
3         1       11/10/20     10
4         2       12/10/20     30
5         3       14/10/20     25
```

**As you can see,**

cust_id = `1` on `10/10/20` with bill `20` and paid `20`

cust_id = `1` on `11/10/20` with bill `10` and paid `10 + 10`

cust_id = `2` on `12/10/20` with bill `30 + 30 + 30 + 30` and paid `30`

cust_id = `3` on `14/10/20` with bill `25` and paid `25`

**Derire query output:**

```
app_id cust_id  a_date   price  a_memo  fin_id  cust_id   f_date  paid
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1    10/10/20   20    hello      1       1     10/10/20  20
2         1    11/10/20   10    bye        2       1     11/10/20  10
3         2    12/10/20   30    hi         4       2     12/10/20  30
7         3    14/10/20   25    peace      5       3     14/10/20  25
```

Tried the following sql but i am getting duplicates(like cust_id 1 and 2 where data rows are not the same in two tables):

```
SELECT f.fin_id,
       f.cust_id,
       f.f_date,
       f.paid,
       a.app_id,
       a.cust_id,
       a.a_date,
       a.price,
       a.a_memo
FROM tblfin AS f
LEFT JOIN tblapp AS a ON (f.cust_id=a.cust_id)
AND (f.f_date=a.a_date)
AND (f.paid=a.price);
```

Solution using MySQL is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE for both tables. Especially their primary/unique indices.

Comment: @Akina There is no relationship between the two tables. `app_id` and `fin_id` are PKs.

Comment: Just to clarify, for cust_id = ```1``` on ```11/10/20``` with bill ```10``` and paid ```10 + 10```, you don't care about merging the paid ```10+10```, but only keeping the first row, right? Same with cust_id = ```2``` and their 4 bills on ```12/10/20``` --- you only want to keep the first bill entry and first paid entry for any given client/date/bill=paid pair?

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee Yes, first or last is the same. Just to keep one row. Now my code is making duplicate because i can't make it pick only one.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee I think that before join somehow i must keep one or first paid and then merge...

Comment: @YvetteLee you can either remove their "duplicate" rows before your ```left join``` by using subqueries that group by ```cust_id```, ```a_date```, ```price/paid``` and only keeps the ```MIN(app_id)```, or [if you have MySQL 8.0] use ```ROW_NUMBER()``` to partition these by ```cust_id```, ```a_date```, ```price/paid``` and then use ```WHERE myRowNum = 1``` to just grab the first.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee replace `tblfin` with `SELECT cust_id, f_date, paid, Min(f_id) AS minf_id
FROM tblFinances
GROUP BY cust_id, f_date, paid) AS f` but still getting duplicates. Running this SQL alone it is working, but when it is subquery it is showing duplicates(not all put half results than before).

Comment: You need to do it to ```tblapp``` too; both sides have multiple rows, so any JOIN between them will grab extra rows from both. Do something very similar for tblapp, and if you're still getting duplicates, we'll need to see the results and the updated query to investigate.

Comment: *There is no relationship between the two tables. app_id and fin_id are PKs.* PKs are the only indices in your tables, and shown columns are complete columns list? if so than the task is unsolvable, more precisely it is not deterministic. Simply imagine the case when the table contains two rows with the same (customer_id+date+money) - I do not see the way how to determine what row of this two must be combined with the row in another table. In your sample data - why tthe row fin_id=4 is combined with the row app_id=3, whereas rows app_id=4 and app_id=5 are ignored?

Comment: @Akina One solution which i am trying is to have the desire output and then delete all rows where i have duplicates(`fin_id` and `app_id`). For the rest rows i will do it manually.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee I did it in both and still the same. Read my above comment. I think this will help me. I have 19K rows and my problem are only 250rows. Since i know them i can fix it manually.